# Custom blocks not displaying in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-blocks

For some reason, any new custom block I create on my Drupal 8 site won't display or render in the DOM after placing the custom block in the region that I want. I've tried clearing cache multiple times, but it's as if custom blocks stopped functioning.

I have a few custom blocks that are still working and displaying correctly (from before it stopped working), but I'm afraid if I change them, I won't be able to get them to display again.

Any ideas? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Do you correctly render your regions in your template?, is everything in your region hidden? or just the particular blocks? Did you override your blocks in your template? Is it a regular block or a view, perhaps your view doesn't show results because the filters are wrong?

Comment: @pjcarly Yes, I've followed the Drupal 8 theming guide regarding adding new regions to a theme and it's all set up correctly. Nothing is hidden or overridden. I've tried with both, regular text blocks and view blocks.

The region is rendering in the DOM but the actual block markup itself isn't.

Comment: @Milo525 It's difficult to help without code. Can you post your custom module code (even if abbreviated)?

Comment: Are you working on a local instance and DB? If not, I would recommend that so you test out the issue locally without risking the production environment

Comment: As @RicardoVelhote said, post code to get a better help.

Comment: Are you sure you're remembering to return your element you're creating at the end of your build function? Are you trying any tricky access conditions, if you make a really simple Hello World type element does that work?